# The formula expression is invalid: Field Case is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions

Tags: process-builder

I am using Process Builder (PB) and getting below error

> The formula expression is invalid: Field Case is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

```
AND(
   OR(
      [Case].RecordType.DeveloperName = 'AH_Pay', 
      [Case].RecordType.DeveloperName = 'AH_Bank'
      ),
[Case].Status = 'On Hold'
)
```

When I query

```
SELECT Id, Name,DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE  DeveloperName IN ('AH_Pay','AH_Bank')
```

I got the data. Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status is a Picklist, so you need to use the IsPickVal function:

```
AND(
   OR(
      [Case].RecordType.DeveloperName = 'AH_Pay', 
      [Case].RecordType.DeveloperName = 'AH_Bank'
      ),
ISPICKVAL([Case].Status,'On Hold'))
```